# The length of the train and test sets are different from the length of the actual set

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

I'm using `test_forecast` and I have my code setup like this

```
df_train <- df[1:20] 
df_test <- df[21:nrow(df)] 

test_forecast(actual = df, 
              forecast.obj = forecast,
              train = df_train, 
              test = df_test)
```

Every row in the df is accounted for in df train and df test.

But, it gives me this error

```
Error in test_forecast(actual = df, forecast.obj = forecast,  : 
  The length of the train and test sets are different from the length of the actual set
```

`df` is a data table, but I also tried this converting all the objects to data frames and that didn't work

Comment: Don't you want `my_df[1:20, ]` instead? And the same missing comma for the test data set but `my_df[21:nrow(my_df), ]`. Or `df_test <- my_df[-(1:20), ]`.

Comment: In your call to `test_forecast()` you have `actual = df`. Is `df` your actual data? Is `df` the same as `my_df`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, it's a data table so the slicing works the same way as df[1:20, ]

Comment: @BenNorris, sorry my mistake. I updated it to be correct

Comment: Have you tried the `ts_split` function as shown in the function example, and compared this to your result?  `split <- ts_split(df, length(21:nrow(df)); test <- split$test; train <- split$train`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with a data frame and a data table and got exactly the same error message.

After reading carefully `test_forecast` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TSstudio/versions/0.1.2/topics/test_forecast), I found :

> actual:    The full time series object (**supports "ts", "zoo" and "xts" formats**).

The conclusion is that `test_forecast` **isn't supposed to work with data.frames / data.tables.**

As you didn't provide the data you're using, I tried [this example](https://ramikrispin.github.io/TSstudio/articles/forecasting.html) which worked:

```
library(TSstudio)
ts <- USgas
ts_par <- ts_split(ts, sample.out = 20)

train <- ts_par$train

test <- ts_par$test

ts_info(train)
ts_info(test)

library(forecast)

md <- tslm(train ~ season + trend)

fc <- forecast(md, h = 20)
test_forecast(actual = ts,
              forecast.obj = fc,
              test = test)
```

[image]

Another important point is that you shouldn't subset a timeseries as you would do with a data.table, because it becomes `numeric`, so that it won't work with `test_forecast`:

```
class(USgas[1:20])
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: @Cauder, see also the last remark I just added at the end of my answer.